# SQL : I am only getting one row returned per user

Tags: sql

I need all the rows returned for games 'flashcards' for each user.

At the moment I am only getting one row returned for each user.

```
SELECT  
    s.name as Escuela,
    sc.class_description as Clase, 
    u.level as "Nivel Del Alumno",
    CONCAT(u.firstname," ",u.lastname) as Nombre,
    stats.game_type as "Tipo de Juego",
    MIN(stats.time) as "Tiempo en Segundos",
    SEC_TO_TIME(stats.time) as "Tiempo en Formato"
FROM 
    game_statistics stats 
INNER JOIN 
    users1 u ON stats.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN 
    school_classes sc ON u.class_id = sc.id
INNER JOIN 
    schools s ON s.id = sc.school_id
WHERE 
    stats.game_type LIKE 'flashcards' 
GROUP BY 
    s.name, sc.class_description,
    u.level, Nombre, stats.game_type
ORDER BY 
    s.name, sc.class_description,
    u.level, stats.game_type, stats.time
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (That query is a bit invalid...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query. You have to include wild card character of `%` to get all rows containing the text `flashcard`. Whenever you use `LIKE` operator in a query you should use wild card characters else the purpose of using `LIKE` is defeated.

```
SELECT
    s.name AS Escuela
   ,sc.class_description AS Clase
   ,u.level AS "Nivel Del Alumno"
   ,CONCAT(u.firstname, " ", u.lastname) AS Nombre
   ,stats.game_type AS "Tipo de Juego"
   ,MIN(stats.TIME) AS "Tiempo en Segundos"
   ,SEC_TO_TIME(stats.TIME) AS "Tiempo en Formato"
  FROM game_statistics stats
  INNER JOIN users1 u
    ON stats.user_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN school_classes sc
    ON u.class_id = sc.id
  INNER JOIN schools s
    ON s.id = sc.school_id
  WHERE stats.game_type LIKE '%flashcards%'
  GROUP BY s.name
          ,sc.class_description
          ,u.level
          ,Nombre
          ,stats.game_type
  ORDER BY s.name, sc.class_description, u.level, stats.game_type, stats.TIME
```

Comment: Hi. Before I was getting one row per user. Now I get none. I copy and pasted your code in. Tgen I used mine and just added the wild card character but I'm afraid I get no rows back now.

Comment: Hi. I get nothing. But when I remove the wild card character it works.

Comment: Yes noticed that and  I just modified my query. Thanks for that.

Comment: @user3149225, I made a small change in query. So try it out now.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks.